# Adjust grid lines in ggplot+geom_tile (heatmap) or geom_raster

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, grid, heatmap

This heatmap has a grid builtin, which I am failing to find the way to customize.

I want to preserve horizontal lines in the grid, if possible increase thickness, and disable vertical lines. Each row should look as a continuous time-serie where data is present and blank where it is not.

Either adding vertical/horizontal lines on-top would possibly cover some data, because of that grid lines, or controlled gaps between tiny rectangles, is preferable.

[image: heatmap with geom_tile]

Alternativelly, `geom_raster` doesn't shows any grid at all. With which I would need to add the horizontal lines of the grid.

[image: heatmap with geom_raster]

I tried changing linetype, the geom_tile argument, which does seem to change the type or allow to fully disable it with linetype=0, fully disabling the grid, but it wouldn't allow to preserve horizontal grid-lines. I didn't saw any changes by modifying the size argument.

This is the code generating the plot as above:

```
ggplot( DF, aes( x=rows, y=name, fill = value) ) +   
    #geom_raster( ) +
    geom_tile( colour = 'white' ) +
    scale_fill_gradient(low="steelblue", high="black", 
                        na.value = "white")+
    theme_minimal() +
    theme( 
      legend.position = "none",
      plot.margin=margin(grid::unit(0, "cm")),
      #line = element_blank(),
      #panel.grid = element_blank(),
      panel.border = element_blank(),
      panel.grid = element_blank(),
      panel.spacing = element_blank(),
      #panel.grid = element_line(color="black"),
      #panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
      plot.caption = element_text(hjust=0, size=8, face = "italic"),
      plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust=0, size=8),
      plot.title   = element_text(hjust=0, size=12, face="bold")) +
    labs( x = "", y = "",
      #caption= "FUENTE: propia",
      fill = "Legend Title",
      #subtitle = "Spaces without any data (missing, filtered, etc)",
      title = "Time GAPs"
    )
```

I tried to attach `DF %>% dput` but I get **Body is limited to 30000 characters; you entered 203304.** If anyone is familiar with a similar Dataset, please advise.

[image: dataset screenshot]

Additionally,

- There are 2 gaps at left&right of the plot area, one is seen inbetween the y-axis, and at the right you can see the X-axis outbounding, and are not controlled by a `plot.margin` argument.
- I would want to set the grid to a thicker line when month changes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following data set has the same names and essential structure as your own, and will suffice for an example:

```r
set.seed(1)

DF <- data.frame(
  name = rep(replicate(35, paste0(sample(0:9, 10, T), collapse = "")), 100),
  value = runif(3500),
  rows = rep(1:100, each = 35)
)
```

Let us recreate your plot with your own code, using the `geom_raster` version:

```
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot( DF, aes( x=rows, y=name, fill = value) ) +   
    geom_raster( ) +
    scale_fill_gradient(low="steelblue", high="black", 
                        na.value = "white") +
    theme_minimal() +
    theme( 
      legend.position = "none",
      plot.margin=margin(grid::unit(0, "cm")),
      panel.border = element_blank(),
      panel.grid = element_blank(),
      panel.spacing = element_blank(),
      plot.caption = element_text(hjust=0, size=8, face = "italic"),
      plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust=0, size=8),
      plot.title   = element_text(hjust=0, size=12, face="bold")) +
    labs( x = "", y = "", fill = "Legend Title", title = "Time GAPs")

p
```

[image]

The key here is to realize that discrete axes are "actually" numeric axes "under the hood", with the discrete ticks being placed at integer values, and factor level names being substituted for those integers on the axis. That means we can draw separating white lines using `geom_hline`, with values at 0.5, 1.5, 2.5, etc:

```r
p + geom_hline(yintercept = 0.5 + 0:35, colour = "white", size = 1.5)
```

[image]

To change the thickness of the lines, simply change the `size` parameter.

<sup>Created on 2022-08-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Hi Allan, I appreciate the workaround. It will do the job. But, can you confirm that there is no-chance to adjust the grid parameters ?

Comment: @DiegoJArg it's not really a work-around. It's the natural way to do it. In ggplot, everything is made of graphics primitives, so all the different components are just different ways of drawing lines, rectangles etc. There are lots of other ways of doing this, but the end result is what matters, and all the other ways of producing the same plot would require a lot more code. This method only requires 1. Is there something you would like to change about the appearance of it?

Comment: Understood. I was expecting the grid to be performed by empty pixels calculated in between the rectangles, pushing each rectangle at the sides. That way, I would have the chance to make vertical lines for certain events without cover any piece of data. Like "month change", "weekends", "quarantine", etc.  It is also possible to add those vertical lines on the background, but this current solution is not able to make a transparent grid to see pixels drawn on the background.